# Car accelerating on its own in BeamNG Drive?

Tags: steam, controllers, beamng.drive

I have been playing BeamNG.Drive with my steering wheel and Pedals ( logitech driving force EX ) When I am in first gear the car slowly moves / accelerates on its own without pressing the gas pedal. When I go up a gear   the car starts to moves even faster! Also when I am in reverse the car also moves backwards on its own. when I unplug the wheel and pedals the car acts normally and has no issues. I am not sure if this is a problem with my controller, or if it is a game bug.

Comment: Is there any way to set a deadzone on the gas pedal? It's possible that it's sending a small amount of input. Check the controls menu